# How to fix ERR_UNSAFE_PORT in android chrome

Tags: android, google-chrome, elixir, cowboy, plug

I have a super basic http server made with plug_cowboy in elixir.
When I send a request with curl, it works as expected,
but when I do that in google chrome, it shows a ERR_UNSAFE_PORT error. This has never happened with a nodejs or python server.

**Note:** I am runing it on an android mobile. I have seen a lot of examples of adding chrome flags in windows, so don't say me the same thing